# using strpos and check next character is number

Tags: php

```
$getword = "apple(code to check if next character of apple is number)";
$storedtext = "apple2";
$getpos = strpos($storedtxt, $getword);
echo $getpos;
```

Result would be 0 cause it finds apple with a number as next character

is this possible? or there are other solutions to my problem. Thanks

Comment: whats your problem

Comment: @ArunKumaresh I want to find the exact words using strpos so I can get the string position. I tried preg_match but it only returns boolean.

Comment: show your input and output you want